Discord bot / Rust Console
Iv made a discord bot and iv been trying to connect it to my gportal game server..
There's no public api, so iv tried to doing it with puppeteer and selenium, (selenium worked best)
With that method I got as far as getting the bot to write the command in the console box on the gportal website and it then sent the command, but it only worked the one time.
So i tried a method with http POST.
With this method I could not get it to work. So iv been running out of ideas on how to make this work efficiently.
Any help would be appreciated.
